# Using x-editable to change image attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'd like to user x-editable for bootstrap to change (for example) the twitter username stored in a data field of a link. The link doesn't contain text but only an image:

```
<span class="socialicon">
  <a href="#" id="si_twitter" data-si-url="https://twitter.com/%USER%" data-si-user="dasaweb">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555402380594786304/3trx0uRj_200x200.jpeg" title="Twitter" />
  </a>
</span>
```

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
$('a[id^="si_"]').each(function(){$(this).editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '#',
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: $(this).find('img').attr('title'),
    placeholder: 'Username',
    defaultValue: $(this).data('si-user'),
    tpl: '<span>' + $(this).data('si-url').split('%USER%')[0] + '</span><input type="text"></input><span>' + $(this).data('si-url').split('%USER%')[1] + '</span>'            
})});
```

I've tried a lot but have no more ideas... Here's a short JSFIDDLE for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dasaweb/kczoj1un/ It would be great if anybody have an idea how I can edit a data field (or the title attribute of the image, or ...)